Quorum queue filtering?
Is there a way to filter messages in a quorum queue like in a stream ?
The considered use case is that application A sends a request message to application B throught RabbitMQ. Then it listens for an answer message on another quorum queue.
There are several instances of application A and, once they posted their request, they all listen to the same answer queue.
Is there a way to have RabbitMQ dispatch each answer message to the right application A instance ?
It seams that stream based filtering provides such a feature ; but what if I would like to use a quorum queue ?
And, if the filtering feature is not available for quorum queues, is there a reason why ?
Kind regards,
Laurent

After internal discussions, stream filtering seems not to intended for such a use.
The proposed solution is that application A publishes its request message along with a unique callback URL.
From there, an additionnal and dedicated component is in charge of subscribing to and consumming the answer queue.
For each answer, it will call the provided callback URL to forward the message to the targeted application A instance.
If the callback fails, the component does not acknowledge the message from the queue so that it remains available for later retry.
Regards,
Laurent
